# Assigning Wired Connection to One Exchange Email Account on OSx Mavericks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, email, microsoft-outlook, osx-mavericks

On my 10.9.2 Mac at work, I am connected two ways to the network, wireless and wired. I need to plug in via a wire to access my email over the company intranet, but when I do that, all of my personal email services stop working and my Google Drive ceases to function. I can disconnect the wired connection and my personal email comes online when connected to wifi. I assigned the wifi a higher priority while both are connected, but it kills my company email.

I'd like to know how to do one or two things:

The first, and ideal, way to handle all of this is to be able to have my work and personal emails in the mail app but have the work email only be retrieved over the wired network while the rest are retrieved from the wireless network.

If that's not possible, then I also have my work email in Outlook 2011 for Mac. I'd like to know how to make Outlook connect over the wired connection and everything else connect via wireless.

I'm on Mavericks. My wired connection:

```
IP: 172.26.XXX.XXX
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 172.26.XXX.XXX

DNS Servers: 162.55.XXX.XXX, 10.13.XXX.XXX
```

My wireless connection:

```
IPv4: 10.240.XXX.XXX
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 10.240.XXX.XXX
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.